# There's a space when I strcpy a string into another string

Tags: c, console-application, dev-c++

I have a kind of logical assignment here in my class. So my question is when I try to strcpy() a string into another string, There's a (like space) in my new string. I don't know how to delete that, perhaps my mistake. Please help me, thank you.

This program let's you type whatever letters or symbol on your keyboard and try to capture it and count the symbol. Then, return it.

Here's my code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 25
typedef char string[N];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i,j;
    int jumlah[10];

    string inputan;
    string temp;
    int counter;

    //Init
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        jumlah[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        temp[i]='-';
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        inputan[i]='-';
    }


    do {

        system("cls");
        printf("\nMasukan kalimat: ");fflush(stdin);gets(inputan);

        if(strcmpi(inputan,"0")!=0) {
            strcpy(temp,inputan);
        }
        getch();

    }while(strcmpi(inputan,"0")!=0);


    printf("Hasil Analisa:\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {

        if(temp[i]!='-') {

            char c = temp[i];
            for(j=0;j<10;j++) {

                if(temp[j]!='-') {

                    if(c == temp[j])
                        counter+=1;

                }

            }

            jumlah[i] = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }

    }


    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {

        if(temp[i]!=' ' && temp[i]!='-' && temp) {
            printf("\t%c terdapat %d\n",temp[i],jumlah[i]); 
        }

    }

    getch();

}
```

And here's my console result:

[image: There's a space]

So that's make the program will show the space symbol and count it.

And if I can ask again, how to display only one char if there's a symbol again in another index that have same symbol. Thx, forgive me if my English is not fluent.

Comment: Are you aware that in C, "string"s are null-terminated (with `0` or equivalently `'\0'`) char arrays?

Comment: Forgive me, I don't know about what is null-terminated. Can you explain it? Thx @Bob__

Comment: Ah, I see @Bob__ Thx for helping me.

Comment: C string is a char array with the last array element == to NULL, or '\0'. for example for the following string: `char stringArray[] = {"sample"}; `stringArray` contains the following: `|s|a|m|p|l|e|0|`.

Comment: suggest using `strcat()` rather than `strcpy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space(s) showing up at the end of your printout are because the list of test conditions you include:

```
if(temp[i]!=' ' && temp[i]!='-' && temp)
```

May be missing some additional conditions that need to be excluded:
1) added additional test: `test[i] != 0`
2) changed `temp[i] != ' '` to `!isspace(temp[i])`, which will test against all white space.

Once these are added:

```
if(!isspace(temp[i]) && temp[i]!='-' && temp && (temp[i] != 0))
```

The text entered is printed only down to the last non-whitespace character.

Code modifications:
I added some other minor modifications to the following code that allowed the code to be compiled in my environment.  Because my modifications use functions that are part of the C standard libraries, this should compile for you as well.
Changes also include expanding `for(...)` loops to accommodate the array sizes you created, enabling input up to `N-1` characters as opposed to only 10.  Most of what I did includes commented explanations.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i,j;
    //int jumlah[10]; 
    int jumlah[N]; // probably meant to use N here?

    string inputan = {0};
    string temp = {0};
    int counter = 0;// initialize

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        jumlah[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
        temp[i]='-';
    }

    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
        inputan[i]='-';
    }


    do {

        //system("cls");  This is fine, just does not work in my environment, so commented.
        //printf("\nMasukan kalimat: ");fflush(stdin);gets(inputan);
        printf("\nPut Sentence (or \"0\" to process): ");fflush(stdin);gets(inputan);// clarified instructions.

        if(stricmp(inputan,"0")!=0) {  //strcmpi
            strcpy(temp,inputan);
        }
        //getch(); this (or getchar()) is really not necessary here to support
        //         the flow of your application.

    }while(stricmp(inputan,"0")!=0);



    printf("Hasil Analisa:\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) { //replace 10 with N

        if(temp[i]!='-') {

            char c = temp[i];
            for(j=0;j<N;j++) {  //replace 10 with N

                if(temp[j]!='-') {

                    if(c == temp[j])
                        //counter+=1;
                        counter++; // var++ equivalent var += 1

                }

            }

            jumlah[i] = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }

    }


    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {

        //if(temp[i]!=' ' && temp[i]!='-' && temp) { // only spaces ?
        if(!isspace(temp[i]) && temp[i]!='-' && temp && (temp[i] != 0)) { // temp[i] != 0, and exclude all white space
            printf("\t%c terdapat %d\n",temp[i],jumlah[i]); 
        }

    }

    getchar();    //orig getch() not standard

}
```

Addressing your question: *how to display only one char if there's a symbol again in another index that have same symbol.*

Displaying a list of the characters used, and the number of times used might be better handled in a separate function.  The one below can be adapted to be called in your original main function by inserting the following lines:

```
char *res = letterCounter("this is the string");
printf(res);
free(res);
```

Just under your existing line: `printf("Hasil Analisa:\n\n");`
(i.e. replace all your code under that line down to the `getch();` function;

```
char * letterCounter(const char *string)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(string);
    char *dup = StrDup(string);
    if(!dup) return NULL;
    int viewableAscii = '~' - '!'; /// range of ASCII from ! to ~ (33 - 126)
    char buf[20];
    char * results = calloc(100*strlen(string), 1);//ensure enough room
    if(!results) return NULL;
    /// caps 'A' == 65, 'Z' == 90
    /// lowr 'a' == 97, 'z' == 122
    /// all visable printables: 33 - 126
    unsigned char characterUsageCounter[viewableAscii];
    memset(characterUsageCounter, 0,viewableAscii); 

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<viewableAscii;j++)
        {
            if(dup[i]  == 33 + j)
            {
                characterUsageCounter[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<viewableAscii;i++)
    {
        if(characterUsageCounter[i] > 0)
        {
            if(characterUsageCounter[i] == 1) sprintf(buf, "%c occurs %d time\n", i+33, characterUsageCounter[i]);
            else sprintf(buf, "%c occurs %d times\n", i+33, characterUsageCounter[i]);
            strcat(results, buf);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

For example, if the string "this is the string" were passed as the argument to that function, the following would be output:
[image]